# multiply numpy.array a with leading dimension of numpy.array b

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, `a` and `b`, where a has dimension 1 and the same length as the leading dimension as `b`, e.g.,

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.rand(5)
b1 = numpy.random.rand(5)
b2 = numpy.random.rand(5, 3, 11)
```

I would like to multiply each "row" of `b` with the corresponding entry in `a`, and get an array of the same shape as `b`.

Something like

```
a[:, None, None] * b2
```

only works if I know the dimensionality of `b` beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
 (a * b.T).T
```

This produces a contiguous array if b is contiguous

```
(a*b.T).flags.contiguous
# False
(a*b.T).T.flags.contiguous
# True
```